# expanding container to content missing the 1%

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-9

im currently working on this site:

http://dingwangbag.com/

Unfortunately i still have a problem with the slideshow:
most browsers seem ok by now ( sometimes still a little flicker at the end but it shows up )

my HTML setup is like this

```
<content>

    <gallery_item>
        <image>
        <image>
        <image>
    <gallery_item>

    <gallery_item>
        <image>
        <image>
        <image>
    <gallery_item>

</content>
```

on document.ready a function is called that runs
this block of code for every image after it has been fully loaded 
(basically getting the width of every image and adding it to the container width)

```
function show_image(image){

          var $item = $(image.img);
          img_width = Math.ceil(parseInt($item.width()));

          gallery_width += img_width;       
          $("#content").width(gallery_width);

          if(images_loaded === false){
                 $item.css("opacity",0);
                 $item.removeClass('offscreen');

                 $item.animate().animate({
                        opacity: 1
                        }, 2000, function() {
                        // Animation complete.
                        });
          }
};
```

and this block is runs on resize

```
(".gallery_slides").each(function(i){
          current_slide_item = $(this);
          current_slide_item_width = 0; 

          $(this).find("img").each(function(){
             current_slide_item_width += $(this).width();    
          });

          gallery_width += current_slide_item_width;       
   });

   $(".gallery #content").width(gallery_width);
```

simple right

its workin so far
but it seems to me that the scaling of the images result in some odd numbers wich sum up to a value that might be 1 or 2 px short 
resulting in the last container not beeing positioned properly (all containers and images are floated left) 
NOW where are these off numbers come from and how can i fix it 
( i added 2px to the container width did help )

BUT

internet explorer 9 is doing something really special
by being somewhat reactive to scrolling and the mouse position
randomly showing or hiding images (even within the group)  *SOB*

and i swear i have no hover or scroll functionality accociated with this in any way

so if anyone could have a look at it and hopefully help me this would be great

thanks in advance

Comment: What version of Jquery are you using, there are some known "bugs" between IE and JQUery and some of the af version specifik

Comment: //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: hmm I can`t find any know bugs about this at least :( sry

Comment: could have been a hint. ty  did u check the page did u see the issue ? i will install IE 10 and 11 and see if they have problems with it as well  but i think i should fix it for IE9 as well

Comment: I did check the page but I do not have IE nor Windows on any of my systems

Answer (score 0):

Don't `ceil`it.

`img_width = parseInt($item.width());`

Also: you should update jQuery to 1.11.1 There have been bugs in the versions before.